# Stuck with 'here document `EOF' unclosed'

Tags: bash, ftp-client

I'm trying to write a bash script but I'm still getting this error:

```
here document `cmd' unclosed
```

I don't know what is wrong; please can you help?

```
#!/bin/bash
USER='login'
PASS='password'

echo $USER
echo $PASS

cd /tmp
for plik in *.tar.gz
do
    echo $plik  
    ftp -niv 192.168.12.2 << cmd
    user $USER $PASS
    cd /centrala/nagrania
    put $plik
    bye 
    cmd
done
```

I'm looping over all `*.tar.gz` for send multiple files to ftp server and this error is stopping me.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ftp -niv 192.168.12.2 <<-cmd
    user $USER $PASS
    cd /centrala/nagrania
    put $plik
    bye 
cmd
```

As per manual:

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters
>   are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

That means you need to use `<<-` form to have natural indentation of your code using tab characters.

Comment: right :) i was remove all tab and now is working :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

- **By default**, a **here-doc *closing* delimiter must start at the *very beginning of the line***, otherwise it won't be recognized.
- Alternatively, if you **prefix the *opening* delimiter with `-`**, then the ***closing* delimiter may have leading *tabs*** - but only true `\t` characters, not spaces.
  Note that this **also strips leading tabs from the lines of the document itself**.

It is **unfortunate that `bash` offers no option to trim leading *spaces* (too)**, given that many editors have the option to insert multiple spaces instead of true tab (`\t`) chararacters when the user presses the TAB key.

Since the difference between multiple spaces and genuine tabs:

- is usually not obvious (you typically can't tell by looking at it, as in the question),
- copying and pasting may even quietly *convert* from tabs to spaces

the **more *robust* solution is NOT to rely on using the `-` prefix** - sadly, at the expense of readability (depending on how the string is used, leading spaces in the document itself - as opposed to the closing delimiter - may still be acceptable, though):

```
# ...      
for plik in *.tar.gz
do
    echo $plik  

    cat << cmd
user $USER $PASS
cd /centrala/nagrania
put $plik
bye 
cmd

done
```